# React.js Component Re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-5

Besides `this.setState` and `this.forceUpdate` methods, are there any other ways or events that would trigger a component re-render from within itself?

I am asking this from a `react-redux` point of view, which I read calls `this.forceUpdate`. I also read that `React.js` discourages the use of this method. That's why I got curious. I'm hoping I didn't misunderstand or get misled by my sources of information.

Answer (score 1):

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    objects: state.objectIds.map(id => state.objects[id])
  }
}
```

This method when passed to connect,

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)`
```

redux will provide new props, which has to be captured in the "component will receive new props", which further invokes render method.

Comment: This one is correct, if we map redux to props of the component, then the render will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method to achieve this :

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){

    //Compare the nextProps and nextState with current props or state respectively if it matters,then :
    //If returned true, the component will re-render if it's false there will 
    //be no change

    return true;  

}
```

Comment: This is totally wrong, this life cycle method is to conditionally prevent rendering, instead of what OP asking